# Vertical alignment of nested table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nesting

I have two tables nested inside of a larger table. One of the nested tables is taller than the other, and I'd like to have the two tables line up together at the bottom. I've tried inserting `[b]` in the outer table, and I've tried declaring the outer table's column containing the shorter inner table as `b{0.25\textwidth}` instead of `l`. Neither of these worked. I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so maybe there's something basic that I'm missing.

Here is a minimal version of what I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
A & B \\ 
\begin{tabular}{rC{5em}}
aaa & 1 \\ 
bbb & 2 \\
ccc & 3 \\     
ddd & 4 \\ 
eee & 5 \\ 
fff & 6 \\ 
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[b]{rC{5em}}
ddd & 4 \\ 
eee & 5 \\ 
fff & 6 \\ 
\end{tabular} \\ 
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

This is what my code is giving me:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiB17.png]

But I'd like to have something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7EY6.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment specifier for a `tabular` could be considered an "anchor point". Use `[b]` for *both* the inner `tabular`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
  A & B \\ 
  \begin{tabular}[b]{rC{5em}}
    aaa & 1 \\ bbb & 2 \\ ccc & 3 \\ ddd & 4 \\ eee & 5 \\ fff & 6
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[b]{rC{5em}}
    ddd & 4 \\ eee & 5 \\ fff & 6
  \end{tabular} \\ 
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```